# Passing JavaScript variables to Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, datatables

I'm specifically looking at how this tool works:

https://datatables.net/extensions/tabletools/

How does the JavaScript variable get to Flash?

It looks like there is an `embed` that is retrieved with `getElementById`, and that element has all of these extra methods on it like `appendText` or `setCharSet` that do not show up in Chromes debug console. I figure the `embed` tag is maybe special and can somehow call native ActionScript methods, but that is just a guess.

Could someone please explain to me how this works?

EDIT: I should have said that if I create an `embed` element in Chrome and scroll through its methods, I do not see things like `appendText`. However, if I console log the `embed` that was retrieved via `getElementById` and `console.log` `appendText`, it says `function() { [native code] }`.

Answer (score 1):

Using this maybe? i never tried this but besides this option not sure how you could do it
http://www.permadi.com/tutorial/flashjscommand/

Comment: i think this is on the right path, but it looks a bit dated.

Answer (score 1):

You use `ExternalInterface` to communicate between the swf and the swf container, i.e. the html page.

You do it exactly like this: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have time to code an example right now, but will do so on your request sometime in the next 24hours. I thought that this would shove you in the right direction for the moment, as this is how I always handle this sort of stuff.

Comment: yes, i did some research and see how people use ExternalInterface. it doesnt look like the example i gave is using that though!

Comment: What is the importance of having the same method as this website?